# Java SimpleDateFormat interprets 'z' differently on different OS

Tags: java, date, datetime, jakarta-mail, simpledateformat

I've following code (simplified to focus on issue). That prints the timezone information using `SimpleDateFormat` pattern.

Do you know why z is treated differently on different machines ? And if there is a way to tell Java to treat it uniformly across all the machines ?

This class is being used in [JavaMail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaMail) and that is causing our email headers to include time which is not comply with [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateFormatTest {
    String PATTERN = "z";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(this.PATTERN);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new DateFormatTest().printTimezone();
    }

    public void printTimezone() {
        System.out.println(this.simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }

}
```

Output : Windows / Mac

```
PDT
```

Output : Linux (CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)) / Ubuntu 14 / 18

```
GMT-07:00
```

Comment: could you specify which RFC (and section) is violated ?

Comment: RFC2822 and the format string in question is `EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)` used by java mail. On Linux this format string generates `Sat, 22 Sep 2018 22:20:17 -0700 (GMT-07:00)` but on mac `Sat, 22 Sep 2018 22:17:44 -0700 (PDT)` (missing timezone offset)

Comment: @Gopinath `RFC 2822 - Internet Message Format - IETF Datatracker` ??? probably RFC 822 which is an uppercase `Z`, not the lowercase `z`

Comment: Its RFC2822 as documented here on Java Mail API https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MailDateFormat.html. Anyways, the puzzling question is what influences output of lowercase `z` of a format string? Some environments the out of `z` has timezone with offset and other environments its just timezone.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I suspect that the observed behaviour doesn’t come from `SimpleDateFormat` behaving differently on those operating systems, but from the time zone setting being different on your different devices (or JVMs). Your code uses the default time zone, which often comes from the OS setting. But as has been said, you shuoldn’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and hence shouldn’t need to worry.

Comment: Why are only 5 tags allowed? I should have liked to add [timezone] and/or [timezoneoffset] and possibly [datetime-formatting]. You may consider one of those in excahnge for one you already have (I didn’t want to make the choice for you).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## tl;dr

Never use `Calendar`. Use *java.time* classes instead.

For strings in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) / [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) format:

```
OffsetDateTime
.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME )
```

> Mon, 24 Sep 2018 23:45:21 GMT

To get the current offset-from-UTC in a particular time zone:

```
ZoneId
.systemDefault()
.getRules()
.getOffset(
    Instant.now() 
)
.toString()
```

> -07:00

## Avoid `Calendar`

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time*. Never use those legacy classes; they are an awful wretched mess.

Your particular issue about **`Calendar` behavior is moot** as there is no need to ever be using that class again. Even when interoperating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert easily between the legacy & modern classes via new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

…and…

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

## java.time

Apparently you want the current offset-from-UTC for your current default time zone.

Get the current default time zone, a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or specify ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) or so on.
```

Ask for the [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) in that time zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

Get the offset-from-UTC in effect in that zone at a certain moment. We will use the current moment, a `Instant`.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( now ) ;
```

Generate a text representing that offset-from-UTC.

```
String output = "At " + now + " in zone " + z + " the offset is " + offset;
```

> At 2018-09-24T23:38:44.192642Z in zone America/Los_Angeles the offset is -07:00

## RFC 1123 / RFC 822

You mentioned an RFC but did not specify. Perhaps RFC 1123 / 822 ?

A [formatter for that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) is built into *java.time*.

```
OffsetDateTime nowInUtc = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
String output = nowInUtc.format( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

> Mon, 24 Sep 2018 23:45:21 GMT

### ISO 8601

FYI, that RFC 1123 / RFC 822 format is a *terrible* format.  It assumes English. It is difficult for machines to parse, and difficult for humans to read. But I understand that you may need it for outmoded old protocols.

Just know that modern protocols use [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. Conveniently, these formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Kudos for completeness.

Comment: FWIW, `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)` produced `Mon, 24 Sep 2018 22:16:36 -0700`. Shouldn’t that be OK with the RFCs too if the asker prefers?

Comment: @OleV.V. Sure, that works too. (a) The Question is not really clear about what zone or offset was actually  the goal. (b) I tend towards using UTC unless there is a clear reason not to.